# Joomla - Hiding a module in category view

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Iam making a Joomla site using Joomla 2.5 and K2. I have a category list showing K2 items. 
I have some modules i need to hide from the category list, but the modules needs to be shown when the user clicks on the article item.

Hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery

```
$('.divname').click(function(){
    $( ".moduletable_sufix" ).show();
});
```

when, you click on article which have class 'divname' moduletable with class 'moduletable_sufix' show. On css template you must set '.moduletable_sufix' { display:none}, I do it like this on page [tanie strony internetowe](http://www.webpiksel.pl/)